# AWS Python Lambda - How do i run a job ONLY when a crawler is finished running?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

Here is the code snippet I am working with. I need to run a job BUT ONLY after a crawler has finished running successfully:

Is it better to create a cloudwatch trigger?

many thanks

```
#update crawler 

response =  glue_client.update_crawler(
Name = 'crawler name',
Role = 'role to be used by glue to create the crawler',
DatabaseName = 'database where the crawler should create the table',
Targets = 
        {
            'S3Targets': 
            [
                {
                    'Path': event['path']   ########## get actual path
                }
            ]
})
        
# invoke crawler
glue_client.start_crawler(Name = 'crawler name')


######## wait for crawler to finish running successfully #########


# invoke job 
        
job_run = glue_client.start_job_run(
               JobName = 'my_test_Job',
               Arguments = {
                 'migration_id':   event['migrationId'] }
```

Comment: Did you take a look on AWS Step functions? https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/  Your requirement let me think of the usage of step function, so I can also decide about the result of the previous job -> success: run Lambda failed: do somethin else

Comment: Side note: Waiting for the Glue crawler complete is probably too long and costly ($) for the runtime of a Lambda function (anti-pattern). Consider using an orchestration framework like MWAA (Airflow) for this use case.